# UICollectionView cell does not showing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have defined an UI for my App. There is a `UICollectionView` which is 100% defined in `Main.StoryBoard`. I have a fixed number of cells and each cell image has an image in it. I have setup the number of cell and image for each cell in `Main.StoryBoard`. However, when I launched the App, the `UICollectionView` is empty. It does not show any cell. What is wrong? Do I have to define a class for this `UICollectionView`? Do I have to write any ObjectiveC Code?

Comment: did you set datasource and delegate  ?

Comment: can you put code snippet here ?

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: Yes, you have to write some code to display in `UICollectionView`. Refer this good tutorial of [Appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

Comment: vimeo is blocked here so i not able see your link.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 5; // put your array count 
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell;

    cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GIVEYOURCELL_IDENTITIFER" forIndexPath:indexPath];// same identifier storyboard cell

    UIImageView *thumbail = (UIImageView*) [cell viewWithTag:YOURCELLIMAGETAG]; // give tag here that you put in cell with imageview 

    thumbail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];// give your image here 
    return cell;
}
```

Main Point give `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate` **Delegates** in your .h file and also from storyboard to your viewController.